# AnyLogic: how to disassemble an agent into two or more new agents?

Tags: anylogic

There is a block named assembler in process modeling library. what should we do to do vise versa, in other words to disassemble an agent into some new agents? should we use multiple split blocks or something else?

Comment: yes, use multiple split blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `Split` element. Please check the help and tutorials where it is covered in depth. See https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fprocessmodeling%2Fsplit.html&resultof=%22%73%70%6c%69%74%22%20

Comment: thanks Benjamin, I knew about split and how it works,but I was eager to know is there any simpler way for disassembling an agent into more than two new agents. something like assembler block. anyway thanks again.